# about jquery counter++ counter--

Tags: jquery, html

I've tried to make some +1 and -1 buttons for a website I'm making and  it works decently on only 1 object. But when for example I've already pressed one button 7times and it says 7, when I press another button it goes to 7+1. I tried making different variables for each button but it didn't work. So my question is how to fix that, how to make each button work for themselves.

Also, while I'm at it, how can I effectivize this code as much as possible? Is there any way to write the JS code in a fewer lines?

```js
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addMe").click(function() {
    counter++;

    $(".theCount").text(counter);
  });
  $(".removeme").click(function() {
    counter--;

    $(".theCount").text(counter);
  });

  $(".addMe2").click(function() {
    counter++;

    $(".theCount2").text(counter);
  });
  $(".removeme2").click(function() {
    counter--;

    $(".theCount2").text(counter);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <img src="../Bilder/lakritsone.jpg" alt="bild på något">
  <div class="theCount">0</div>
  <button class="addMe">+1</button>
  <button class="removeme">- 1</button>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="../Bilder/lakritsone.jpg" alt="bild på något">
  <div class="theCount2">0</div>
  <button class="addMe2">+1</button>
  <button class="removeme2">- 1</button>
</li>
```

Comment: `[...] tried making different variables for each button but it didn't work[...]` how did you try that, and why did it not work?

Comment: You can use the `data()` function to store values per object, so you do not need a global variable.

Comment: for example I tried var counter = 0 var counter1 = 0 etc

Comment: You should add additional information to your question and not as a comment. Using `var counter = 0; var counter1 = 0;` should - even so it would not be an elegant solution - have worked, so you would need to show a complete example with that code that does not work as you expect. Anyhow the links duplicate should cover all of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".addMe").click(function() {
  var target = $(this).parents('li').find(".theCount");
  var count = parseInt(target.text().trim())
  count += 1;
  target.text(count);
  });
  
  $(".removeme").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).parents('li').find(".theCount");
  var count = parseInt(target.text().trim())
  count -= 1;
  target.text(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <img src="../Bilder/lakritsone.jpg" alt="bild på något">
  <div class="theCount">0</div>
  <button class="addMe">+1</button>
  <button class="removeme">- 1</button>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="../Bilder/lakritsone.jpg" alt="bild på något">
  <div class="theCount">0</div>
  <button class="addMe">+1</button>
  <button class="removeme">- 1</button>
</li>
```